# "in the case in which" in other words

Tags: synonyms

I find the construction "in the case in which" slightly cumbersome. Is there any alternative I can use in the following sentence:

- *The third research question was posed in order to find alternative solutions towards safer learning in the case in which the approximate dynamical model is unavailable.*

In addition, in the original formulation, I used "in the case when". A colleague of mine says this is incorrect. Anyone can explain why? British National Corpus online [1] finds both examples, although very few.

Thanks for help!

[1] http://bncweb.lancs.ac.uk

Comment: That link doesn't work for non-members.

Comment: I would say: In the case WHERE one man kills a fly.....

Comment: Try _The third research question was posed in order to find alternative solutions towards safer learning **where** the approximate dynamical model is unavailable_. You could also use _when_ here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get rid of all of the stuffy cruft and just go with **when**:

> The third research question was posed to find alternative solutions for safer learning when the approximate dynamical model is unavailable.

I also removed "in order" and changed "towards" to "for". I'm not 100% sure what preposition carries the meaning you want, but I'm fairly certain "towards" isn't it.

Comment: Thank you! I though about just removing it all, but somehow could not make it myself:)

Comment: I also wasn't sure about "dynamical" vs. "dynamic", but left it in case "dynamical" is a jargon term in your field.

Answer (score 1):

The English idiom is:

**in the case **of** someone or something**. [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+case+of)

> in the matter of someone or something; in the instance of someone or
>   something. In the case of John, I think we had better allow his
>   request. In the case of this woman, we'll not grant permission.